# Is it possible to create a template class with later type definition?

Tags: c++, templates

Assume this pseudocode:

```
Generic<unknown_type>* p;

if (type == A)
 p = new Generic<AClass>;
else if (type == B)
 p = new Generic<BClass>;
else
 p = new Generic<CClass>;
```

Is it possible to create pointer to template class without type?

Comment: Template parameters are meant to be known in compile time. You should look into an alternative, such as dynamic polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to determine template type during the execution time, but this denies the very nature of the templates in C++, which are designed to be determined during compilation.

Thus, what you are trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to declare a template class, use pointers to it, and later provide the definition.  But that's not actually what your code is trying to do.

You're trying to declare and use a variable with incomplete type.  That's not permitted.  You could however parameterize the whole piece of code, so it too becomes a template.  Then it reads more like:

```
Generic<TypeParam>* p = new Generic<TypeParam>;
```

and depending on `TypeParam`, can be expanded (only at compile-time) to any of the three cases you show.

To do type selection at runtime, you'll need a common base class.  Template specializations are not automatically related by inheritance in any way.

Answer (score 0):

No. That's not possible.

`Generic<AClass>`, `Generic<BClass>`, and `Generic<CClass>` are all different types without a common base class.